# How do WebSocket Clients work in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, websocket, threadpool

My question is more related to how WebSockets (on the client) work/behave with threads in .Net and what I am looking for as an answer would be more of a low level explanation on how the OS interacts with the .Net thread when it receives data from the server on its socket.

Suppose I have a client that opens 1000 sockets to a server asynchronously. It then sits there waiting for updates/events to come through. These events can arrive at different times and frequencies.

Assuming that every time data comes in via a socket, a thread needs to pick it up and do some work on it, am I correct to assume that **IF** all the 1000 sockets receive data at the same time I will then have 1000 threads (1 thread per socket) coming from the Thread Pool to pick-up the data from the socket? What if I wanted to have 3000 sockets open?

Any clarification on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Web socket servers like Ngnix don't use threads to manage the connections. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [.NET Framework library WebSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket(v=vs.110).aspx) the received data will be returned on a thread from the ThreadPool (probably the IO Completion Thread Pool).

**Thread Pool**
When the thread pool is used you don't know how many different threads that will be active a the same time. The data is put on a queue and the thread pool works through it as fast as it can. You can control the min/max number of threads that it will use, but the way that the pool creates/destroys its threads is unspecified.

The above hold true for most asynchronous operations in .NET.

**Excpetions**
If you awaited the asynchronous receive operation in a synchronization context (for instance a UI thread) the operation will resume in the same context (UI thread), unless you suppress the sync context. In this case only one thread will be used and the receive operations will be queued and processed in sequence.